# Is there a word for the diamond thing hanging on the ceiling?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I am pretty sure there's a word for that, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a **[chandelier](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chandelier)**. Definition from Merriam-Webster: a branched often ornate lighting fixture suspended from a ceiling.

One like your picture could be described as a **crystal chandelier**.